# find and update duplicates in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am looking for a Pythonic way to solve the following problem. I have (what I think is) a working solution but it has complicated flow controls and just isn't "pretty". (Basically, a C++ solution)

I have a list of lists.  Each list contains multiple items of varying types (maybe 10 items per list)  The overall order of the lists is not relevant, but the order of the items in any individual list is important. (ie I can't change it).

I am looking to "tag" duplicates by adding an extra field to the end of an individual list.  However, in this case a "duplicate" list is one that has equal values in several preselected fields, but not all fields (there are no "true" duplicates).

For example:  if this were the original data from a 5 item list of lists and duplicate is defined as having equal values in the first and third fields:

```
['apple', 'window', 'pear', 2, 1.55, 'banana']
['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 3, 1.80, 'banana']
['apple', 'envelope', 'star_fruit', 2, 1.55, 'banana']
['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 0.80, 'coffee_cup'] 
['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 3.80, 'coffee_cup']
```

The first, fourth and fifth lists would be duplicates and therefore all lists should be updated as follows:

```
['apple', 'window', 'pear', 2, 1.55, 'banana', 1]
['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 3, 1.55, 'banana', 0]
['apple', 'envelope', 'star_fruit', 2, 1.55,'banana', 0]
['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 3.80, 'coffee_cup', 2]  
['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 3.80, 'coffee_cup', 3]
```

Thanks for any help or direction.  I think this may be getting beyond the Learning Python book.

Comment: I just realized there are extra commas in the "updated" data set and some of the numbers changed.  That is an error.  Also the last list in the first set is there by mistake.  Please ignore it.  Only the number added to the end of the list was supposed to change.  I am sorry everyone.  Cut and paste error.

Comment: ['apple','window','pear',2,1.55,'banana',1] ['apple','window','pear',2,1.55,'banana',0] ['apple','orange','kiwi',3,1.80,'banana',0] ['apple','envelope','star_fruit',2,1.55,'banana',2] ['apple','orange','pear',2,0.80,'coffee_cup',3]

Comment: Why a list deleted? Are you numbering the duplicates or deleting?

Comment: Can you edit that into your original post?

Comment: I think an admin just made the changes.  Thank you.  I feel like an idiot.

Comment: @Wyatt don't worry, they're just fruits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

lists = [['apple', 'window', 'pear', 2, 1.55, 'banana'],
['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 3, 1.80, 'banana'],
['apple', 'envelope', 'star_fruit', 2, 1.55, 'banana'],
['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 0.80, 'coffee_cup'],
['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 3.80, 'coffee_cup']]

dic = defaultdict(int)
fts = []
for lst in lists:
    first_third = lst[0], lst[2]
    dic[first_third] += 1
    if dic[first_third] == 2: fts.append(first_third)
    lst.append(dic[first_third])

for lst in lists:
    if (lst[0], lst[2]) not in fts:
        lst[-1] -= 1

print(lists)
```

Edit: Thanks utdemir. `first_third = lst[0], lst[2]` is correct, not `first_third = lst[0] + lst[2]`

Edit2: Changed variable names for clarity.

Edit3: Changed to reflect what the original poster really wanted, and his updated list. Not pretty any more, desired changes just tacked on.

Comment: There were 6 entries in the first list when I posted this.

Comment: But; (ll[0]="ab", ll[2]="c") is same as (ll[0]="a", ll[2]="bc") on your code. Maybe creating a tuple is better.

Comment: @don-odonnell It works fine. `d = defaultdict(int)` is right out of the examples section of http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict Edit: I don't know why you'd think I'm appending to int; it's calling d[key] = int() when I try to access a key that doesn't exist.

Comment: @agf: Sorry, comes from reading your code too quickly. Misread `l.append` as `d.append`. I realized my error and deleted my comment but not quick enough apparently. BTW, `l` is an awful variable name, very hard to distinguish it from the number `1`, at least on my screen.

Comment: @don-odonnel: True. Comes from writing a brief snippet and my brain throwing in brief (and easily confused) variable names. Edited for clarity.

Comment: OK...I have now studied and tried this solution.  It ALMOST works.  The only problem I ran into was that in a group of duplicates the first duplicate gets a zero instead of a one.  Other matches would also have to be +1 relative to the results.

Comment: I've edited my post to change the counter for non-duplicates to zero. Please accept my answer if it's now what you were looking for.

Comment: Alright.  I will try your changes.  Hopefully, it works and I will be back to "accept"  Thanks!

Comment: This works!  Thanks a lot!  Is there some way for me to formally accept this answer and give you some reputation points?  Sorry, I am still quite new here.

Comment: Click the check mark under the number next to my post. And thanks for asking how, I appreciate it.

Comment: Done!  Thanks again to you and everyone who read and contributed.  I still plan on studying the other posts to just to learn what the heck happened. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to sort the list first using `itemgetter()` to select the fields to be matched as `key`. This will cause all matching key fields to appear together so they can easily be compared and tagged. For example, the sort for matching the first and third fields would be:

```
lst.sort(key=itemgetter(0, 2))
```

The comparison of each item with its predecessor is straight forward.

Okay, here is the complete solution (uses itemgetter and groupby):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def tagdups(input_seq, tag, key_indexes):
    keygetter = itemgetter(*key_indexes)
    sorted_list = sorted(input_seq, key=keygetter)
    for key, group in groupby(sorted_list, keygetter):
        group_list = list(group)
        if len(group_list) <= 1:
            continue
        for item in group_list:
            item.append(tag)
    return sorted_list
```

And here is a sample test run to show usage:

```
>>> samp = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,3,5,7,7],[1,4,3,5,8],[4,3,2,7,5],[1,6,3,7,4]]
>>> tagdups(samp, 'dup', (0,2))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dup'], [1, 4, 3, 5, 8, 'dup'], [1, 6, 3, 7, 4, 'dup'], [1, 3, 5, 7, 7], [4, 3, 2, 7, 5]]
```

Comment: a nice resolution, maybe you can provide more code for wyatt how to find the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution(commented code):

```
import itertools

l = [
        ['apple', 'window', 'pear', 2, 1.55, 'banana'],
        ['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 3, 1.80, 'banana'],
        ['apple', 'envelope', 'star_fruit', 2, 1.55, 'banana'],
        ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 0.80, 'coffee_cup'],
        ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 3.80, 'coffee_cup']
    ]

#Here you can select the important fields 
key = lambda i: (i[0],i[2])

l.sort(key=key)
grp = itertools.groupby(l, key=key)
#Look at itertools documentation
grouped = (list(j) for i,j in grp)

for i in grouped:
    if len(i) == 1:
        i[0].append(0)
    else: #You want duplicates to start from 1
        for pos, item in enumerate(i, 1):
            item.append(pos)

#Just a little loop for flattening the list
result = [] 
for i in grouped:
    for j in i:
        result.append(j)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 3, 1.8, 'banana', 0],
 ['apple', 'window', 'pear', 2, 1.55, 'banana', 1],
 ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 0.8, 'coffee_cup', 2],
 ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 2, 3.8, 'coffee_cup', 3],
 ['apple', 'envelope', 'star_fruit', 2, 1.55, 'banana', 0]]
```

Comment: I will definitely have to study this a while.  If this works, that you a ton.  I have looked at lambda functions (as of yesterday) but could not see where they would be useful.  I am just about to learn a lot.  Thank you.